# SQL to join two tables

Tags: sql, database

I have a question on how to join two tables, I have the following tables

```
ITEM_TAB
--------------------------------------------------
ItemID, Qty, Price, EleCode, WomCode, MenCode
--------------------------------------------------

CODES_TAB
--------------------------------------------------
CODE     |   TYPE             |        DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------
AA       |     ELECTRONICS    |          ...
AA       |    WOMEN           |           ...
AA       |   MENS             |          ...
BB       |    GROCERY         |           ....
BB       |     DELI           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Item table contains only codes(EleCode is of TYPE Electronics, WomCode is of TYPE Womens etc), and CODES is a lookup table. These two do not have any association. In a single query I need to retrieve like the following.

ItemID, Qty, Price, EleCode, Desction, WomCode, Description, MenCode, Description.

```
select i.itemId
    , i.Qty
    , i.price
    , i.EleCode
    , (select description from code where code='AA' and TYPE='ELECTRONICS')
    , i.WomCode
    , (select description from code where code='AA' and TYPE='WOMEN')
    , i.MenCode
    , (select description from code where code='AA' and TYPE='MENS') 
from ITEM
```

Could you please help me in framing this query.

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or Oracle? Both tags don't belong there, unless you're actually using both DBMS. If you added the `oracle` tag because of Java, please remove it; it's like using `microsoft` as a tag for a `windows7` question - the manufacturer or trademark owner is irrelevant, because you know who owns/publishes `windows7`. (Actually, why is this tagged `java`? There's no reference to any programming language here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ItemID, Qty, Price, EleCode, e.description, womcode , w.description, mencode, m.description
from item_tab
left join codes_tab e 
on (eleCode = e.code)
left join codes_tab w 
on (womcode = w.code)
left join codes_tab m
on (mencode = m.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

my someone did you a big favour with  this schema didn't they?

Something like

```
Select ItemId,Qty,Price,Elecode,e.description,womcode,w.description,mencode,m.description
left join codes_tab e On e.Type='ELECTRICAL' and e.code = elecode
left join codes_tab w On w.Type='WOMENS' and w.code = womcode
left join codes_tab m On m.Type='MENS' and m.code = mencode
```